# How to change the height of individual row in a HTML table using row border?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, resize

I am looking for a way to be able to change the height of a row in a table, not to a preset size if possible, by selecting the row border and dragging it.

The scenario is as follows:
I have certain data being represented in the rows of the tables. Depending on the height of the row, the representation of the data may vary i.e. it might be a summary of the data if the row height is small, but may be the detailed description if the height is beyond a certain size. I want to be able to select the row in question and drag it to change its height.

If free flow change is not possible for some reason, I can make do with 3 levels of height. Scenario being, if i drag the row height beyond set limit x, it snaps to the next higher limit x'.

I understand you can change the size of the table elements/rows using css/js to fit predefined conditions, but I was unable to find anything to suit my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In normal case( without use of plugins) , it is not possible to make a row of table re sizable  with mouse. So, alternatively you can implement the rows using CSS. You can check the jsfiddle  that i have create dfo you here. http://jsfiddle.net/sakirullahi/Npuyc/5/

In this i have used **resizable** event in jquery.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the fiddle. Also, you mentioned that without plugin it was not possible to resize individual rows of table, do you happen to know any plugin which can help do what you did using css?

Comment: There is a plugin to support this by [Ben Alman - the jQuery resize event plugin][1], which allows `resize` .
[You can test out a demonstration of it with a `<tr>` here][2].


  [1]: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/
  [2]: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/FLw3r/